# CORS issue between Angular 10 and Spring Boot 1.5

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I just can't solve a CORS issue between my angular 10 application and spring boot 1.5.

I've tried everything that i can and it's still not working.
I'm trying to set a global CORS config to allow everything

My current implementation:

```java
@Configuration
public class DevConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                    .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
    
}
```

And I'm getting this on the frontend side:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/test' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Version

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.7</commons-io.version>
    <spring.version>1.5.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

**[EDIT]**

I've changed that to this:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
    
import java.util.Arrays;
    
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
    {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Requested-With", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

And it's still not working

Comment: Have you checked this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Basically the description that is under the title "Global CORS configuration" thats' what i'm doing

Comment: Can you share your controller where you have the "test" mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Add `@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")` in the method or controller level in your RestController. Or,

If you want to add global configuration, configure this bean in your configuration file:

```java
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() 
{
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Requested-With", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

If you're using spring security, you should add `configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);` here too and don't forget to add `http.cors()` in spring security configuration.

**Edit:**

When the browser is making a cross-origin request, the browser adds an Origin header with the current origin (scheme, host, and port). On the server side, when a server sees this header, and wants to allow access, it needs to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the response specifying the requesting origin (or * to allow any origin.). When the browser sees this response with an appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, the browser allows the response data to be shared with the client site.

If your backend is sending the header, this might likely be that Chrome does not support localhost to go through the Access-Control-Allow-Origin. To have Chrome send Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the header, just alias your localhost in your /etc/hosts file to some other domain, like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost yourdomain.com
```

Then if you'd access your api using yourdomain.com instead of localhost, the call should succeed.

If the problem still exist, You need to check whether any header is sent by the backend. If not, add that to response headers (that's nasty). Let me know what actually happened.

Comment: Thanks for your help. but its not working

Comment: have you added `@CrossOrigin` on your controller? @Anna

Comment: Should I add it there even if it's configured globally?
But even if i'm adding it it's not working, i don't know what's going on really

Comment: @Anna, are you getting this cors error only from browser or from postman too?

Comment: Only browser.
```Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/test/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
zone-evergreen.js:2845 GET http://localhost:8080/test/ net::ERR_FAILED```

Comment: @Anna please edit your post and add browser request found in inspect -> network, I've edited my answer, have a reading of the edited part.